# JavaScript global function

Tags: javascript

I have a function in a JavaScript file:

myscripts.js:

```
function myOn(node,event, selector, data, handler)
{
    document.write("This text comes from an external script.");
}
```

and in the HTML file, I have this:

```
<body>
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>

...//some text and tags
<script>
            myOn(outer, 'click','.deleteButton ', "", deleteDiv);           
</script>
<body>
```

the function "myOn" don't run in the HTML file.

How i make this work?

I have searched the internet, but found some hard example for me to understand.

I need a simple example for beginner like me.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the function definition, there shouldn't be another parenthesis inside the parentheses

This line:

```
function myOn(node,event, selector, data, handler(eventObject))
```

should be:

```
function myOn(node,event, selector, data, handler)
```